# Repository pattern to query multiple databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, architecture, n-tier-architecture

This is a very weird architecture. Please bear with me.

We have an existing tiered application (data, logic/service, client).
The latest requirement is that the service layer should access two data sources!!!! (no other way around)
These two data sources have the same DB schema.

As with most tiered architectures, we have read and write methods like:

```
IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts(),
Product GetProductById(ProductKey id),
IEnumerable<Product> FindProductsByName(string name)
```

the product DTOs are:

```
class Product
{
    public ProductKey Key { get; set;}
    ...
}

class ProductKey
{
    public long ID { get; }
}
```

We narrowed it down to two possible solutions:

Alternative 1:
Add a parameter into the read methods so that the service knows what DB to use like so:
Product GetProductById(ProductKey id, DataSource dataSource)
`DataSource` is an enumeration.

Alternative 2 (my solution):
Add the DataSource property to the key classes. this will be set by Entity Framework when the object is retrieved. Also, this will not be persisted into the db.

```
class ProductKey
{
    public long ID { get; }
    public DataSource Source { get; } //enum
}
```

The advantage is that the change will have minimal impact to the client.

However, people dont like this solution because

- the `DataSource` doesn't add business value. (My response is that
  the `ID` doesn't add business value either. Its a surrogate key. Its
  purpose is for tracking the persistence)
- The children in the object graph will also contain `DataSource` which is redundant

Which solution is more sound? Do you have other alternatives?

Note: these services are used everywhere.

Comment: The database schemas are the same but is there anything about the DTOs themselves that would provide a clue as to which datasource to go to?  At what point would a key or DataSource get set from the client's perspective?

Comment: The client will pick which datasource to search from (ex: GetAllNewProducts([the datasource]) ). The returned products can then be view-able and (editable if it came from datasource A) in another view. Note that this view will perform additional queries to get the items related to the product (ex: GetRelatedProducts(ProductKey)).

Comment: I extended the ObjectContext (or DbContext) to automatically set the DataSource when the object is created from a query.

Comment: The DTOs can only go to one datasource. the other datasource is readonly.

Comment: Instead of picking the datasource by object, can you just switch the connectionstring globally?  Or is it per product or item that they can switch things out?

Comment: the user can view multiple products from any datasource at any time. each product is displayed in tab like a web browser. plus, this is a multiuser environment.

Answer (score 4):

What I would suggest is door number 3:

```
[||||||||||||||]
[|||||||||s!   ]
[||||nerics!   ]
[  Generics!   ]
```

I use a "dynamic repository" (or at least that is what I have called it). It is setup to be able to connect to any datacontext or dbset while still being in the same using block (i.e. without re-instantiation).

Here is a snippet of how I use it:

```
            using (var dr = new DynamicRepo())
            {
                dr.Add<House>(model.House);
                foreach (var rs in model.Rooms)
                {
                    rs.HouseId = model.House.HouseId;
                    dr.Add<Room>(rs);
                }
            }
```

This uses the "default" dbcontext that is defined. Each one must be defined in the repository, but not instantiated. Here is the constructor I use:

```
    public DynamicRepo(bool Main = true, bool Archive = false)
    {
        if (Main)
        {
            this.context = new MainDbContext();
        }
        if (Archive)
        {
            this.context = new ArchiveDbContext();
        }
    }
```

This is a simplified version where there are only two contexts. A more in depth selection method can be implemented to choose which context to use.

And then once initialized, here would be how the Add works:

```
    public void Add<T>(T te) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        dbSet.Add(te);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

A nice advantage of this is that there is only one spot to maintain the code for interacting with the database. All the other logic can be abstracted away into different classes. It definitely saved me a lot of time to use a generic repository in this fashion - even if I spent some time modifying it at first.

I hope I didn't misunderstand what you were looking for, but if you are trying to have one repository for multiple data sources, I believe this is a good approach.

Comment: The problem isn't the DbContext. We just use different connection strings for that. Our current repository accepts "Product GetProductById(ProductKey key)". How can I modify so that the repository knows which DB to access?

Comment: @LostInComputer - Without modifying the `GetProductById` signature?

Comment: That is alternative 1 which I wrote in the question. See above.

Comment: @LostInComputer - I see, well what you could do, although this might not work if you are already using inheritance on your `ProductKey` class, is to use `ProductKey` as a base class and then inherit from it with `MainProductKey`. So, `class MainProductKey : ProductKey{}` would allow you to use reflection inside of your repository to determine the source of the database while still retaining the signature of `GetProductById`. In addition, `AlternateProductKey : ProductKey{}` would allow a different database connection to be used.

Comment: That is also a good suggestion. I will tag it as alternative 3!